How do I update a scheduled AzureML pipeline?
I have a scheduled AzureML pipeline that I want to update in my CI/CD pipeline. The only way I can see is to disable pipeline and schedule and re-create the objects.
Is there a better way to do it?
Example:
ws = Workspace(
    subscription_id="",
    resource_group="",
    workspace_name="",
)

pipeline = Pipeline(…)

published_pipeline = pipeline.publish(…)

schedule = Schedule.create(
    workspace=ws,
    name="my_schedule",
    pipeline_id=published_pipeline.id,
    experiment_name="my_experiment",
    recurrence=my_recurrence,
    description="My Schedule"
)

new_pipeline = Pipeline(…)
# How do I replace pipeline with new_pipeline?


Are you using sdk v1? add you expected output.

Both in sdk v1 and v2 you have to create schedule objects.
You cannot add new pipeline to the existing schedule.
The update method just updates the schedule and not the pipeline.
For every pipeline there will be 1 or more schedules but every schedule will be having one pipeline.
Check this for 2 pipelines

Even in sdk v2 only you can change the job definition for schedule but cannot add 2 jobs to a schedule.

So it is correct, that the only way to go is to disable old pipeline and schedule and create new ones?

You need to created new schedule for new pipeline. If you don't want to run your old pipeline then disable the schedule.
